# Concatenate two inputs of different dimension at a specific index in a sequence in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, word-embedding

I am trying to train an LSTM using two types of embedding layers. Let's say that the following is my tokenized sentence:

```py
tokenized_sentence = ['I', 'am', 'trying', 'to', 'TARGET_TOKEN', 'my', 'way', 'home']
```

Now for the words surrounding the "TARGET_TOKEN" I have an embedding layer which is (vocab_size x 128) while for the token 'TARGET_TOKEN' at index 4 I have an embedding layer which is (vocab_size x 512). So I need to transform the TARGET_TOKEN embedding from 512 to 128 and then insert this 128 dimension vector at index 4 (this index will change depending on the feature) of the output from the surrounding words embedding layer before feeding this concatenated list (tensor) to the LSTM. In my situation the positioning of the words/tokens is very important and so I do not wish to lose the position of where the token 'TARGET_TOKEN' is in the sentence.

Initially I was looking on how to reduce the size of the 512 embeddings and I found that with numpy I could take the average of every 4 adjacent vectors and thus I end up from 512 dimensions to 128 dimensions. However, it is to my understanding that this might not represent the vectors in the right way anymore.

Let's call the token 'TARGET_TOKEN' as "target_token" and the rest of the words as "context_tokens". So instead after further reading I thought could take the output of the target_token embedding layer and pass it through a Dense layer with 128 units (thus reducing its size to 128). Following this I will concatenate the output of the Dense layer with the output of the context_tokens embedding layer. So far I know how to do this. My issue is that positioning is important and it is important that my LSTM learns the target_token embedding with respect to its surrounding context. So long-story-short I need to concatenate at index 4 (maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way but that's how I understand it).

However, the concatenate layer in Keras does not have such a parameter and I can only concatenate the two layers without taking into consideration the positioning.

My model will take three inputs:

```py
input1 = target_token
input2 = context_tokens
input3 = target_token_index
```

and one output (as a sequence).

My code looks like this:

```py
target_token_input = Input((1,))
sentence_input = Input((None,))
index_input = Input((1,), dtype="int32")

target_token_embedding_layer = Embedding(500, 512, weights=[], trainable=False)(target_token_input)

target_token_dense_layer = Dense(128, activation="relu")(target_token_embedding_layer)

context_embedding_layer = Embedding(self.vocab_size, 128, weights=[self.weight_matrix],
                                                trainable=False)(sentence_input)

concatenation_layer = Concatenate()([target_token_dense_layer, context_embedding_layer])

bidirectional = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=self.return_sequences, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))(concatenation_layer)

normalization_layer = BatchNormalization()(bidirectional)

output_layer = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.output_size, activation=self.activation))(normalization_layer)

model = Model([target_token_input, sentence_input, index_input],[output_layer])
```

My expected result should be the following, here the numbers represent the dimensions of the the token vectors.

```py
original_tokens = ['I', 'am', 'trying', 'to', 'eng-12345', 'my', 'way', 'home']
vector_original_tokens = [128, 128, 128, 128, 512, 128, 128, 128]
post_concatenation_tokens = [128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128]
```

Notice how at index 4 the embedding went from 512 to 128. I am looking into the possibility of transforming the tensor into a list, inserting the output of the target_token_embedding_layer into this list at the desired index and then transforming the list back to a tensor and using that tensor as input for the LSTM. However, I'm still trying to figure this out.

Does anyone know how to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Umm, the short answer is you can't. You could do it programmatically, where things would look like how you want them to look, but the Keras LSTM wouldn't understand it. The Keras LSTM needs to understand the connections between tokens. When you get a list of embeddings from one "universe" and try to mash it with embeddings from another "universe", things just don't work.

You will have to tokenize / embed all the words in the same dimensions for it to work. I'm assuming that the TARGET_TOKEN has different embeddings (512) compared to the rest of the dictionary? You could create a new embedding which is (128+512). However, since you mention that you reduced the original 512 embeddings to 128, my suggestion is that you should just go back to 512 embeddings.

Note how I mention Keras LSTM: What I wrist is in response to the common, well known LSTM layer with the standard 4 gates. If you are writing your own variation of the LSTM layer from scratch (say in Tensorflow or numpy), all bets are off.

I'm guessing you're trying to build some kind of network that fills in the blanks? What was your reason to switch from 512 embeddings to 128? Saving memory?

Comment: So actually the reason is that I am building on previous work. I have the embedding vectors from the previous work were the TARGET_TOKENs have a dimension of 512 and the context_tokens have a dimension of 128. The reason that they have different dimensions is that they did not need to join the two together. 

So if I understood right, you're saying that I should create new embeddings which are 128+512 (so train new embeddings) and then use these new embeddings?

Would it bad to use the embeddings that I reduced from 512 to 128 by averaging?

Comment: Yes, you need to train new embeddings. You can't average the previous embeddings or combine them with embeddings from another work. Since you are re-training, you could just pick another number of embeddings, i.e. 512 for the entire new dictionary. It doesn't need to be (512+128). I suggest watching Week 2 videos (2 hrs) here (auditing free) (Lectures: [Word Embeddings](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/nlp-sequence-models/using-word-embeddings-qHMK5) [Properties of Word Embeddings](https://www.coursera.org/learn/nlp-sequence-models/lecture/APM5s/learning-word-embeddings)

Comment: I will check out the links that you sent me. Thanks for your help :)